# Change level at which power level notification

Tags: gnome, power-management

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and can't seem to find the right place to change at what level the system sends a notification popup at power level.

I found

```
snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override
```

but this doesn't have a percentage level, just the actions.
I want to change it from 10% to 22%

Comment: try editing `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`. change PercentageLow from 10 to 22 and make sure `UsePercentageForPolicy` is set to true

Comment: ahhh - that's where it was, thank you! I can select as answer if you post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPower.conf

UPower (previously DeviceKit-power) is a piece of middleware (an abstraction layer) for power management on Linux systems. It enumerates power sources, maintains statistics and history data on them and notifies about status changes.

It is located inside `/etc/UPower` directory.

To change the notification of Low power from 10% to 22% edit `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`. 
change `PercentageLow` from 10 to 22 and make sure `UsePercentageForPolicy` is set to true.